# jQuery, creating an HTML block that I can insert into the page

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

```
<div id="box">
<span>stuff.....</span>
</div>
```

What i'd like to do is create a JavaScript variable with this html... Then with jQuery be able to insert that into the page with something like `$('#contentCol').html(mystuff)`

Is there an elegant way to do this rather than a long string of html?

Comment: With over 200 questions you should know how to format code blocks in questions by now...

Comment: I've used string, but wonder if there is something more HAML like for jQuery which I've never done. Just learned of HAML during my Rails studies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ID names are unique, so I changed `id="box"` to `class="box"`, so you can insert the block multiple times.

Simply create a function that returns a jQuery object of the type you want. You can pass the HTML inside the span to the function as an argument:

```
function createBlock(myHTML) {

    $("<div/>").attr("class", "box").append($("<span/>").html(myHTML));
}
```

You can use this function in multiple ways:

```
// Method 1:
var myStuff = createBlock("stuff");
$("body").append(myStuff);
  // or even...
$('#contentCol').html(myStuff)

// Method 2:
$("body").append(createBlock("other stuff"));

// You can of course append wherever you want... or prepend, or before / after
//   or use the jQuery object to build up an even larger block before inserting.
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2H8zQ/)**

Answer (score 0):

in simple javascript you can use createElement and appendChild element etc to create DOM elements at runtime. in jQuery you can do it like

```
jQuery('<div id="box">...</div>').appendTo('#contentCol');
```

Comment: thanks but that's not elegant, it's repeating closing tags etc... Just wondering if there is a cleaner way. thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

its work for me

in html file have a div like

```
<div class="demo">
  <div class="demo">Demonstration </div>
</div>
```

and selector of class is '.demo'

```
$('.demo').html('<form>Name:<input type="text" id="name">'+
        '<br>Pass:<input type="text" id="pass">'+
        '<br><input type="submit" value="confirm"></form>');
```

this replace   `"<div class="demo">Demonstration </div>"` for

```
"<form>Name:<input type="text" id="name">'+
        '<br>Pass:<input type="text" id="pass">'+
        '<br><input type="submit" value="confirm"></form>"
```